# Cannot connect to MySQL on VPS Server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to a VPS server with the following code. What is wrong with it?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("A.B.C.D", "user", "pass", "db1");
if (!$con)  {
    die("Could not connect: ".mysqli_errno());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);

echo $name;

?>
```

The above code gives the error : Could not connect:

However, when I use "localhost" and run this script on a copy of that database and table that I have in my laptop, it runs smoothly and echoes the name from the first record in the table.

Why am I not being able to connect to my VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure MySQL has enabled outside access, you probably don't have access from remote machines to the VPS.

UPDATE: Do you have access to phpmyadmin or a tool like that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following;

- MySql is allowing network connections, other than localhost
- Your firewall is not blocking your MySQL Port
- The user you are connecting with, has either @% access, or your IP

Comment: I have checked the third option, went to 'Edit Privileges' and changed the host from 'Any Host' to my PC's IP from where I am running the PHP script.

How to check if the VPS firewall is blocking the MySQL Port? Or whether MySQL is allowing other connections apart from localhost?

Does Ubuntu 12.04 Server come with a built in firewall or something? I thought someone needs to set that up! I'm such a noob! o.O